# Failed to send the invoioce email

Tags: php, magento

This is the logs:

tail -f var/log/exception.log

```
> #4 /var/www/local.xxxxxxxx.com/application/booktocuba/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(79):
> FFV_MailTransport_Model_Core_Email_Template->sendTransactional('sales_email_inv...',
> 'general', Array, Array, Array, '1')
> #5 /var/www/local.xxxxxxxx.com/application/booktocuba/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(836):
> Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
> #6 /var/www/local.xxxxxxxx.com/application/booktocuba/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php(99):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->sendEmail()
> #7 /var/www/local.xxxxxxxx.com/application/booktocuba/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):
> Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice->emailAction()
> #8 /var/www/local.xxxxxxxx.com/application/booktocuba/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('email')
> #9 /var/www/local.xxxxxxxx.com/application/booktocuba/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> #10 /var/www/local.xxxxxxxx.com/application/booktocuba/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
> #11 /var/www/local.xxxxxxxx.com/application/booktocuba/app/Mage.php(683):
> Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #12 /var/www/local.xxxxxxxx.com/application/booktocuba/index.php(123): Mage::run('base', 'website')
> #13 {main}
```

And code is: app/code/local/FFV/MailTransport/Model/Core/Email/Template.php

```
public function sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars=array(), $storeId=null, $created_in = 'en_EN')
    {

        $this->setSentSuccess(false);
        if (($storeId === null) && $this->getDesignConfig()->getStore()) {
            $storeId = $this->getDesignConfig()->getStore();
        }

        if (is_numeric($templateId)) {
            $this->load($templateId);
        } else {
            $localeCode = $created_in == 'en_EN' ? Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId) : $created_in;
            $this->loadDefault($templateId, $localeCode);
        }

        if (!$this->getId()) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid transactional email code: '.$templateId));
        }

        if (!is_array($sender)) {
            $this->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_'.$sender.'/name', $storeId));
            $this->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_'.$sender.'/email', $storeId));
        } else {
            $this->setSenderName($sender['name']);
            $this->setSenderEmail($sender['email']);
        }

        if (!isset($vars['store'])) {
            $vars['store'] = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
        }

        $this->setSentSuccess($this->send($email, $name, $vars));
        return $this;
    }
```

the object is not capturing data, any ideas please help.
Robert.

Comment: do you recieve any other email from Magento ? does server sends mails at all ?

Comment: Hi Christophe.

Magento takes mailings seamlessly to customers who make purchases on the web, but when I try to send an order or an invoice from the admin panel gives me the mistakes I have shown, it is as if the object does not capture data 'name', 'email', 'vars', can you help me please.

Thank you, Robert